# JMeter: how to vary request inside Thread Group

Tags: jmeter

I have to write load tests for web application using JMeter. The application has items available for booking, each item has a 'Book' button. If some user clicks this button for item, it becomes unavailable for other users. My question is:
Is it possible to make JMeter threads to book different items (to make different requests) and how to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to determine what parameter is being posted by different "Book" buttons and modify nested requests as needed. Test plan structure should be something like:

- Open Booking Page - HTTP Request

  - Get all Booking IDs - Post Processor
- Book - HTTP Request

Where "Post Processor" can be

- [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)
- [CSS/JQuery Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSS/JQuery_Extractor)
- [XPath Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#XPath_Extractor)

In case of multiple matches Post Processor will return multiple variables like

```
BookindID_1=some value
BookindID_2=some other value
BookindID_3=some other value 2
....
BookindID_matchNr=10
```

There are at least 2 options on how to proceed with these values:

1. Iterate all the values using [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller)
2. Stick to current virtual thread number via [__threadNum](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function so thread #1 will take BookindID_1 variable, thread #2 - BookingID_2 variable value, etc.

It is also possible to take random value using [__Random](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) function but it may result in request failure if item is not available.

The correct way of 2 variables combination looks like:

```
${__V(VAR1${VAR2})}
```

So combining `BookingID_N` and `__threadNum` will look like

```
${__V(BookingID_${__threadNum})}
```

See [How to use JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) post series for more on what can be done via functions.

Answer (score 1):

yes, If every item has **static**(predefined) unique id,descriptor,identifier then that can be parameterized using a csv config file or random no. generator and selector

Random no generator and selector will work only for integers but csv config is better/standard practice. If you need more help please paste your test plan here with explaination of your need.